# Не срабатывает правило веб сервера nginx

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx

Скорей всего, ошибка в регулярном выражении, но не могу понять какая.

Пишу вот такое правило:

```
rewrite (.*)\/size\/([0-9]+)\/color\/([0-9]+) $1?size=$2&color=$3 last;
```

Но ничего не происходит.

Вот пример url, который должен срабатывать:

```
http://kupitkamen.ru/catalog/plitnyak/peschanik/size/20/color/27
```

Вот такие правила без проблем срабатывают:

- `rewrite (.*)\/size\/([0-9]+) $1?size=$2 last;`
- `rewrite (.*)\/color\/([0-9]+) $1?color=$2 last;`

Comment: 1. лучше всё-таки ставить привязку к началу и концу строки (посмотрите любой пример rewrite). 2. как вы определили, что «не работает»?

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, всё содержимое соответствующей секции `server`. прямо в вопросе (в комментариях это будет нечитабельно). чтобы внести исправления в текст вопроса, нажмите [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Укажите пожалуйста порядок, в котором следуют правила. Не может более общее правило перехватывать запрос к вашему более конкретному правилу?